# ¿Como puedo validad con regex que se hizo una pregunta?

Tags: javascript, regex

¿Como puedo validad con regex que se hizo una pregunta?¿es posible?
ejemplo:

```
var text = "¿cómo estas hoy? pareces cansado"
text.match(/([¿?]).*\1/)
```

Comment: https://regexr.com/ En esta pagina puedes hacer pruebas sobre `regex` en javaScript

Comment: "No se puede hacer". Las expresiones regulares no entienden de lenguaje natural. Lo único que se podría intentar es que tú definas una serie de reglas que se tienen que cumplir para considerar algo una pregunta (mejor que las digas tú para que se ajuste mas a lo que necesitas) y entonces via regex podremos validar que se cumplan. He puesto una respuesta con algo más de detalle sobre este tema.

Comment: Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Yo consideraría que puede haber o no `¿` pero si hay `?` tiene que haber por lo menos un caracter antes, `?cómo estas hoy pareces cansado` no me parece mucho a una pregunta. Aquí unos ejemplos:

```js
    var text = "¿cómo estas hoy? pareces cansado"//true
    var text2 = "cómo estas hoy? pareces cansado"//true
    var text3 = "cómo estas hoy pareces cansado"//false
    var text4 = "¿cómo estas hoy pareces cansado"//false
    var text5 = "?cómo estas hoy pareces cansado"//false 

    console.log(/¿?.+\?/g.test(text))
    console.log(/¿?.+\?/g.test(text2))
    console.log(/¿?.+\?/g.test(text3))
    console.log(/¿?.+\?/g.test(text4))
    console.log(/¿?.+\?/g.test(text5))
```

De cualquier manera hay muchos aspectos que probablemente no estemos considerando, como que pasa si hay otros signos de puntuación... `.?cómo estas hoy pareces cansado` o espacios..

Comment: Excelente, gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Algunos utilizan "¿" otros no. Creo que buscar si la cadena de texto tiene "?" es bastante. En regex hay que utilizar la contrabarra ( \ ) para escapar el meta carácter "?".

No es necesario utilizar modificadores de la regex ya que si lo encuentras una sola vez es pregunta.

```js
let str = "¿cómo estas hoy? pareces cansado";
let rex = /\?/gi;
let esPregunta = (str.search(rex) > -1) ? true : false ;
console.log(esPregunta);// si es pregunta devuelve true.
```

Espero que mi respuesta sea útil.

Comment: Muchas gracias, excelente.

Comment: Tu ejemplo funciona bastente bien :). Sin ambargo, aunque es muy rebuscado, ¿qué me dices de un texto en el que se hable de los caracteres? Es un caso muy muy poco probable, pero no imposible: "El símbolo de apertura de interrogación es '¿', mientras que el símbolo de cierre de interrogación es '?'". En esa frase no hay pregunta alguna, pero aparece el símbolo.

Comment: Ja Ja Ja!!! Sí que es rebuscado! Esto `/(["'])\??\1/` encuentra '?' o "?" Entonces tendrías que comprobar también que no es una cita. Espero que mejores mi respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

> nota: Escrito esto aquí por que es demasiado extenso para un
>   comentario

La pregunta es complicada, ya que las expresiones regulares únicamente entienden de ciertas reglas simples y no de lenguajes naturales.

Tendrías que definir qué consideras tú una pregunta para poder responder con la mayor precisión posible.

Por ejemplo:

- ¿Las preguntas deben empezar forzosamente con `¿`?
- Se admiten preguntas de una o pocas palabras como: `¿tú?`, `¿quién?`, `¿12.000?`
- O por el contrario, las preguntas deberían ser más elaboradas. En tal caso, ¿bastaría con buscar un mínimo número de palabras? Por ejemplo: al menos 3 palabras: `¿Cómo te llamas?` Si es así, ¿cuántas?

De todas formas recuerda que incluso con la mejor definición de reglas y la mejor ejecución en forma de expresión regular, siempre tendrás casos no detectados y falsos positivos.

Además, tampoco queda claro si intentas buscar diferentes preguntas dentro de un bloque mayor de texto. O por el contrario se entiende que ya tienes separadas las 'frases', y simplemente quieres evaluar si alguna de estas frases es una pregunta.

Comment: Gracias Julio, la idea es hacer una pequeña consola con preguntas muy cortas pero que en principio son limitadas, así quedaría fácil solo con condicionales, pero la idea es no cerrarse a solo esas posibilidades, entonces poder contemplar una soluición lo mas compacta posible,

Comment: Lo dicho, podrías indicar en tu pregunta una serie de reglas mínimas para considerar algo una pregunta. Así podremos contestar con una expresión regular